# CakePHP Form Helper Database Interaction

Tags: mysql, forms, cakephp

Currently I am developing a CakePHP that will list various businesses.

In the database, there is a table for businesses that lists them like so:

> id | name | address | city | state | state_id | zip | url

The state column are abbreviations of states (for listing purposes) CA, AK, FL, etc and the state_id matches up with the ids in the states table:

> id | name | state_abbr

I have an admin_add.ctp template with form helpers for inserting new businesses.
For entering a state for a business I am going to have a pull down that lists all the states. However, how do I make the database insert so it will know how to add the state abbreviation and state id when I submit the form to add the business?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
In my Business controller I have `var $uses = array('business', 'state')` and then in the add function I can pass all the states data to the view of the Add Business page.
Then in the view of the Add Business I set an associative array linking the `state_id` to the state name. Then I can pass that through `$form->input('state_id', array('options' => $stateArray))`.

Answer (score 0):

Save only `state_id` in your `businesses` table, you can always recover the state_abbr whenever you need it from the `states` table. (So delete the `state` field from `businesses`).

Evenctually, to avoid join each time, you can always read the `states` table once and have a mapping state_id=>array("name"=>something,"state_abbr"=>xy) to retrieve that information faster if you need it a lot of times in the same session

Comment: WRT to the "mapping" you discuss, since states are unlikely to change significantly, whenever I deal with them like this I just hard code them into an array that I can call from anywhere in my app.  Makes it super fast, accessible from anywhere.

Comment: What I'm trying to wrap my head around, would be how to have a select with a list of the states, but then when they save it, it would submit the state id not the name.